# how to invoke qtp's object repository lib using C#

Tags: c#, qtp

I met a problem recently. I want to invoke the QTP's Object Repository Lib using C#, but it doesn't work.
code:

```
REPOSITORYUTILLib.ObjectRepositoryUtil or = new REPOSITORYUTILLib.ObjectRepositoryUtil();
or.Load(@"C:\Repository.tsr");
or.GetAllObjects();
```

but I recieved a `System.InvalidCastException` when the program runs to `or.GetAllObjects();`, I don't see any cast operation here, how can I get such exception? 
Does anyone has some ideas? Thanks.

here is the stacktrace:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.ValidateReturnArg(objectarg,System.Type    paramType) + 0xe7 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PropagateOutParameters(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg, object[] outArgs, object returnValue) + 0x88 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(string memberName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags flags, object target, int[] aWrapperTypes, ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData msgData) + 0x26e bytes

test.exe!test.test.Main() lines 14 + 0xf bytes  C#

mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile,     System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6d bytes    
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x2a bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes
```

Comment: hi @Polity,thanks for response,I just post the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1):

QTP object repository is accessible using reflection. Use of reflection will help to get rid of the above error.